# Do superheating and supercooling only occur from liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, nucleation

Superheating of a liquid past its boiling point (retarded boiling) is a well-known phenomenon. However, is there such a thing as supercooling of gas past its condensation point?

Conversely, supercooling of a liquid (retarded freezing) is also well-known. Does the reverse ever occur: can I superheat a solid up past its melting point?

Comment: c.f. [cloud chambers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_chamber) for an application of vapor->liquid transition

Comment: I believe for your question "supercooling of gas" consider humidity 
(supercooled steam), for your second question "superheat a solid" consider dry ice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Superheating and supercooling should be possible whenever there is a first order phase transition. This includes a wide variety of magnetic, structural, and electronic phase transitions. The physical mechanism is the same as in the water-ice transition: in a first order phase transition. the energy functional is still a local minimum at the old phase, there is a barrier to the formation of the new phase and so an adiabatically cooled sample will remain in the old phase past the point when the old phase is a global minimum.